# Not a valid XPath expression

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting error while running the program, If i check my xpath in chropath it gives no error in path but while running i am getting error "valid XPath expression."

```
<article xpath="1">
<div class="imagen">
  <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154/bhgCVGl6BDXS8BfcUGzWU5EWnMb.jpg"> 
  <div id="c28153" data-nonce="9f7f7584d7" data-id="28153" data-type="movie" class="cimport">

</div>
</div>
<div class="data">
    <h3>It's Alive</h3>
    <span>1974</span>
</div>
</article>
```

PYTHON CODE:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[translate(. ," - ; : ! , . * ? / \' " , " " )='its live']//preceding::img[1]//following::div[1]').click()
```

Comment: It seems 'its alive' is behaving like a variable and not a string. I don't know if it's correct. Perhaps it should be =''its live''?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here, what's the point of the xpath expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[translate(. ," - ; : ! , . * ? / \' " , " " )=\'its live\']//preceding::img[1]//following::div[1]').click()
```

just adding **`\`** before the inner **`'`**.

Answer (score 1):

Replace you Xpath string by this one :

```py
'//h3[translate(. ," - ; : ! , . * ? / \' " , " " )="its live"]//preceding::img[1]//following::div[1]'
```

The probleme you have its a mixing of quote, that prematuraly end the string.

Comment: You are right... the problem is mixing the quote but your xpath needs fixing too...

Comment: thanks for reply sir but " driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[translate(. ," - ; : ! , . * ? / \' " , " " )=\'its live\']//preceding::img[1]//following::div[1]').click()
" this works :D thanks again for your reply